# Why Jews are the chosen people?

Tags: judaism

Are the Jewish people the chosen and if so why?...My uneducated Grandmother always said the the Jewish people were the chosen because they were the only people who kept God's laws at that time..such as, feast of the tabernacle, fest of unlevened bread..etc..I am confused. If not born Jewish, are the rest Gentiles? And if the Jewish are the chosen people why are they blinded to the first coming of Christ?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity Stack.  When you have a moment, please please take the Christianity Stack tour to learn more about us:  https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour  
Some years ago a similar question was closed as being “off-topic” because the question did not specify a basis from which to answer, e.g. what is the biblical basis for God choosing a particular people?  Perhaps you could edit your question accordingly?

Comment: Seems like the answers could be tautological.  *Some* people had to be chosen.  The Jews were it.  Therefore they're the chosen people.  *Some* Jews followed Jesus as the Messiah.  They were then known as Christians.  The ones who still today call themselves Jews, therefore, must be the ones who didn't become Christians.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Judaism rather than about Christianity.

Comment: Should not be closed. There can be Christian views about why the Jewish people were chosen, and they may or may not be the same as the Jewish beliefs on the matter.

Answer (score 3):

You really have to define "chosen" here. The Jewish people were "chosen" by God to reveal His Law to, an to have the Tanakh-primised Christ come out of. But as of the time Christ came, the "chosen" are those who have believed that Jesus is the promised Messiah and who have kept His commandments (it's a different topic as to what these are and what defines the keeping):

> "Yet to all who did receive him, to those who believed in his name, he
>   gave the right to become children of God" (John 1:12), "'Abraham is
>   our father,' they answered. 'If you were Abraham's children,' said
>   Jesus, 'then you would do what Abraham did" (John 8:39).

Jesus Christ said that those who keep the Law, besides His commandments, and teaches others so (at least the parts of the Law that were not directly abolished by the New Testament like having to sacrifice animals for atonement from sins - Christ became the ultimate sacrifice once and for all time, see Hebrews 10:12), would be called the greatest in heaven, while those who don't and teach others so, would be called the least in Heaven:

> "For truly I tell you, until heaven and earth disappear, not the
>   smallest letter, not the least stroke of a pen, will by any means
>   disappear from the Law until everything is accomplished. 19 Therefore
>   anyone who sets aside one of the least of these commands and teaches
>   others accordingly will be called least in the kingdom of heaven, but
>   whoever practices and teaches these commands will be called great in
>   the kingdom of heaven" (Matthew 5:18-19).

The reason many Jewish people are blinded as to the coming of Christ is because it is written in the prophets that it would eventually be so, see Isaiah 53:3:

> "He was despised and rejected by mankind, a man of suffering, and
>   familiar with pain. Like one from whom people hide their faces he was
>   despised, and we held him in low esteem".

Answer (score 2):

Abraham was the man chosen by God. He was told consistently that God would make him into a great nation and bless his descendants because of his faith in following God (Gen 12, 15). He was called "the man of faith." God enacted his promises to Abraham through choosing one of his descendants; so, God chose Isaac and then God chose Jacob. Jacob was named "Israel" and was made into a great nation. However, it wasn't the people at large that the promises to Abraham were fulfilled: it was to "Abraham's seed" that was descended from him: Jesus. The promises to Abraham were fulfilled in Jesus. Let's look at Galatians 3:

> 6 just as Abraham “believed God, and it was counted to him as righteousness”?
>   7 Know then that it is those of faith who are the sons of Abraham. 8 And the Scripture, foreseeing that God would justify the Gentiles by faith, preached the gospel beforehand to Abraham, saying, “In you shall all the nations be blessed.” 9 So then, those who are of faith are blessed along with Abraham, the man of faith.

And then in following, we read:

> 16 Now the promises were made to Abraham and to his offspring. It does not say, “And to offsprings,” referring to many, but referring to one, “And to your offspring,” who is Christ.

And so the Jewish people were "chosen" to bring forth the Messiah, the savior of the world. Through Jesus, the world and Gentiles are blessed and Abraham inherits the world through his spiritual descendants. Thus Christians -- those in Christ, are called "descendants of Abraham."

The physical people were blinded to the coming savior because of their hardened heart and lack of faith. These people were seeking to come to God through legalism and obeying the law, Not through the heart of the law, which is to love God and love your neighbor. See the rest of Galatians 3 for the details.

Also, look at Romans 9-11. The promises are not forgotten to the Jews for there is a remnant that continue to come to the Messiah. In the salvation of the remnant of Jews and some Gentiles all of "spiritual Israel" is saved, that is the church. 
In Romans 11,

> 25 Lest you be wise in your own sight, I do not want you to be unaware of this mystery, brothers: a partial hardening has come upon Israel, until the fullness of the Gentiles has come in. 26 And in this way all Israel will be saved

To fully understand, I encourage you to read Galatians 3 & 4, Ephesians 1 as well as Romans 8-11 until you are enlightened!

Answer (score 0):

Deuteronomy 9 says this:

> 3 But understand that today the Lord your God will cross over ahead of
>   you as a consuming fire; He will devastate and subdue them before you.
>   You will drive them out and destroy them swiftly, as the Lord has told
>   you. 4 When the Lord your God drives them out before you, do not say
>   to yourself, ‘The Lord brought me in to take possession of this land
>   because of my righteousness.’ Instead, the Lord will drive out these
>   nations before you because of their wickedness. 5 You are not going to
>   take possession of their land because of your righteousness or your
>   integrity. Instead, the Lord your God will drive out these nations
>   before you because of their wickedness, in order to keep the promise
>   He swore to your fathers, Abraham, Isaac, and Jacob. 6 Understand that
>   the Lord your God is not giving you this good land to possess because
>   of your righteousness, for you are a stiff-necked people.

The people of Israel were not chosen because of their righteousness, but for these reasons:

1) The wickedness of the inhabitabts of the land
2) The promises that God had made to Abraham, Isaac and Jacob.

The choice was his sovereign choice, based on His grace and their faith, not on the recipients deserving it.

Answer (score -1):

Gid set aside Noah in order to save himanity. Then, once humanity continued to sin, he set aside Abraham, out of all peoples and nations to build a representative people. Of Abrahams descendants, he chose Issac, then Selected Jacob,. Then he chose Judah's bloodline out of the twelve tribes to carry the genetic material he would use for psrents. Originally, it would have been the tribe of Benjamin, if Saul had not been so rebellious. Through King David, the bloodline if Judah therefore, becsme the bloodlind if the kingship.

The Jews were chosen to be a royal priesthood to all nations and peoples., They had the job to keep and uphold tve history of the world, to remain clean and set-apart (which God now commands Christisns to do), to be disciplined in all things and to maintain and transmit to all people the will of God. They, being himan, blew most of that.

They kept the history from the beginning of time, then specifically kept the history of the twelve tribes so as to show (so the truth would not be corrupted or forgotten). The seriousness of that role is found in the requirement for each male to make an accurate copy if Torah.

Finally, first via Abraham and his half sister Sarah, the genetic line of Adam and Eve were maintained uncorrupted, and the right to kingship until Jesus was born. After that, the tribes were scattered so that the seed of Abraham could be sprtead out among the other nations and ssnctify them despite the corrupt genes.

The key here is that st some point, the Roman Catholic Church sought to eradicate tbe Jews and then became the stewards of scripture, which slthough they denied access to most people for centuries, they did finally relinquish.

Because God set the Jews aside as his chosen eimmersaries"  we have the evidence of God today. Praise God for choosing them.

Comment: Please [edit] this to fix your typos.